# for loop in bash just runs once

Tags: bash, macos

I'm doing resolution check in bash but this loop just runs once and ends without an error:

```
for file in *; do \
  WIDTH = $(identify -ping -format '%h' $file) \
  HEIGHT = $(identify -ping -format '%w' $file) \
  if [ "$WIDTH" -ge 500 ]; then \
    echo width greater than 500 \
  elif ["HEIGHT" -ge 500]; then \
    echo height greater than 500 \
  fi \
done
```

**Output**:

```
height greater than 500 fi done
```

Why doesn't it check all the files?

Comment: How many files are there? Have you checked to make sure it is working in the directory you think it is?

Comment: 12000+ files, checked with `ls -al`.

Comment: The backslashes are actually wrong here.

Comment: So are the spaces in the assignments. Run your code through http://shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# using bash, not sh, ensures that <(), (( )), and other extensions are available.

for file in *; do
  IFS=: read -r width height < <(identify -ping -format '%w:%h\n' "$file")
  if (( width >= 500 )); then
    printf '%s\n' "$file has width greater than 500"
  elif (( height >= 500 )); then
    printf '%s\n' "$file has height greater than 500"
  fi
done
```

---

- Running `identify` twice doubles the performance impact of invoking an external command; better to run it only once, and read both variables in a single pass. The syntax used to collect the output of the `identify` command into a stream is [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst), whereas the `read` command is rather comprehensively discussed in [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), or [the relevant bash-hackers wiki page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read).
- Backslashes are *line continuations*; they're appropriate when you have a simple command (not a compound command like this one) that spans multiple lines. In this context, they're simply wrong.
- `[` is a **command**, and command names need to be separated from their arguments by spaces. Just as you run `ls -l`, not `ls-l`, you can't run `[foo`; it needs to be `[ foo`, as two separate words. (If it's clearer, consider using the synonym `test`: `if test "$width" -ge 500; then ...`).
- All-caps variable names are specified [by POSIX-defined convention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) to be used for names with meaning for the system and shell, whereas names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use. (The convention explicitly applies to environment variables, but shell variables share the same namespace: setting a shell variable with a name that overlaps an environment variable will overwrite the latter).
- Using `printf` rather than `echo` has better-defined behavior: [the POSIX specification for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html) leaves wide ranges of behaviors undefined, and if printing a filename containing literal backslashes, the behavior of `echo` becomes implementation-dependent and thus nonportable. See in particular the APPLICATION USAGE section of the linked page.
- Using `(( ))` puts you into a math context, where variable names can be used without a preceding `$`, and more natural C-style math syntax can be used, such as `>=` rather than `-ge`. (This is a bashism -- POSIX sh specifies only `$(( ))`, which has similar behavior but is a substitution command; thus, in POSIX sh, one could instead write `if [ "$(( width >= 500 ? 1 : 0))" = 1 ]` to test the results of this substitution).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed explanation. TIL. :)

Answer (score 0):

Asked too soon, figured it out myself using this awesome helper - [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/):

```
for file in *; do 
  WIDTH=$(identify -ping -format '%h' "$file") 
  HEIGHT=$(identify -ping -format '%w' "$file") 
  if [ "$WIDTH" -ge 500 ]; then 
    echo width greater than 500 
  elif [ "$HEIGHT" -ge 500 ]; then 
    echo height greater than 500 
  fi 
done
```

Comment: BTW, running `identify` twice is rather inefficient -- you can read both variables from one invocation. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate.